# What's the fastest/easiest way to download every single mobile app from the App Store and Google Play to a Mac or PC?

Tags: android, ios, automation, app-store, google-play

Yes, I realize there are more than two million apps in total. I'm looking for an automated approach since manually downloading millions of apps is not feasible. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: contact google and apple and see if they will let you access the servers legitametly

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will ever use all the apps which are there on app store or google play store. You can choose and download those which you want. There is no such mechanism available in my opinion which will allow you to download bunch of apps together, you must visit the App Store and manually chose to install which app you want.

Comment: He might be doing a security evaluation and he needs a bunch of `APK`s or `IPA`s to study. (I think its interesting question because I'd like to do the same, even if it is a bit broad for the site. Others will probably land on this answer if someone posts the steps).

Answer (score 0):

Despite this is an offtopic question:

I would suggest you to visit the store website, loop somehow through the apps and fire the download-button-click programatically... this should be possible, but you will soon run out of storage on your pc...